# AWS SageMaker feature group- can it have 2 recordidentifiers

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am following the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/feature-store-fraud-detection-notebook.html to create my sagemaker feature group.

In section 4 there is the step of setting up record identifiers.

In my case a record would have 2 identifiers. The 2 identifiers together make up the unique record in feature store.
How can I achieve this? Is this supported by SageMaker?
If its creation is supported, how does one query this?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK you can only have one record identifier for a feature group. Can you perhaps use a combined feature? If you're using the offline store, you may be able to use the columns as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the community after research on this topic as @durga_sury mentions only one record identifier is possible,
If you want to have 2, the current way is to combine them into a composite identifier and then store in feature store.